# Solving a power function for its coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Can somebody please help me with the following problem.

I want to solve the following power function for the $\phi$ coefficient:

\begin{equation}
\hat{z} = x\phi^\alpha
\end{equation}

I have come up with two solutions.

Solution 1:

Step 1)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\hat{z}}{x} = \phi^\alpha
\end{equation}
Step 2)
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\hat{z}}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha} = \phi
\end{equation}

Solution 2:

Step 1)
\begin{equation}
\log_{\phi}\left(\frac{\hat{z}}{x}\right) = \alpha
\end{equation}
Step 2)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\log_{\gamma}\left(\frac{\hat{z}}{x}\right)}{\log_{\gamma}\phi} = \alpha
\end{equation}
Step 3)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\log_{\gamma}\left(\frac{\hat{z}}{x}\right)}{\alpha} = \log_{\gamma}\phi
\end{equation}
Step 4)
\begin{equation}
\phi = \gamma^{\frac{\log{\gamma}\left(\frac{\hat{z}}{x}\right)}{\alpha}}
\end{equation}

Plotting both functions in Matlab (with a log-log plot) shows that both functions are indeed different
[Plot of both functions taking 1->100 as the X-values. Plot constructed using MATLAB software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfqu8.png)

Can anyone please tell me which derivation is correct?
The first one is simpler, but I believe I have applied the correct laws in the second solution too, yet I have arrived at different results.

Comment: They are not different: $\gamma^{1/\alpha \log_\gamma (\frac{z}{x})}=\gamma^{ \log_\gamma (\frac{z}{x})^{1/\alpha}}=(\frac{z}{x})^{1/\alpha}$

Comment: You probably did a mistake in your matlab coding or matlab is doing something weird for some reason. But both of your calculations are correct and the same.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Maths isn't my strong point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z=x\phi^{\alpha} \implies \ln\frac{z}{x} = \alpha \ln \phi \implies \ln \phi = \frac{ \ln\frac{z}{x}}{\alpha} = \ln \left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \implies \phi = \left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$

So, they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will investigate the MATLAB error.